# Behaviour of snprintf with %s at end of format string

Tags: c, printf

I am building commands with `snprintf()` that i want to execute with `system()`. I noticed that the last character is missing when i use `%s` at the end of the format string but when i am adding an extra space after the `%s` it works as i would expect. Why does this happen? I think i am missing something. I appreciate your help!

Here is an minimal example:

```
#define INTERFACE "can0"

int size;
char *command = NULL;

size = snprintf(command, 0, "/sbin/ifdown %s", INTERFACE);
command = malloc(size);
snprintf(command, size, "/sbin/ifdown %s", INTERFACE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[en.cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) says (emphasize is mine)

> int snprintf( char *restrict buffer, size_t bufsz, const char *restrict format, ... ); (4)

> 4. Writes the results to a character string buffer. **At most bufsz - 1 characters are written.** The resulting character string will be terminated with a null character, unless bufsz is zero. If bufsz is zero, nothing is written and buffer may be a null pointer, however the return value (**number of bytes that would be written not including the null terminator**) is still calculated and returned.

So your first call returns the number of characters that would be written excluding the terminating null character. Your second call to `snprintf` says that `size` characters should be written including the  terminating null character.

So the fix should be to allocate a bigger buffer and to pass `size+1` in the second call.

```
command = malloc(size+1);
snprintf(command, size+1, "/sbin/ifdown %s", INTERFACE);
```

You don't show the code with the extra space. But I guess you have added it to the first call of `snprintf` and maybe also to the second call. In that case your first `snprintf` returns a `size` that is one higher. The second `snprintf` cannot write the additional space, but with the higher `size` it can now write the string as you expect it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats the thing that i was missing.

Answer (score 3):

`snprintf` returns the number of characters printed **not including the null terminator**. Therefore when you pass that size back to `snprintf` it figures out that your buffer is one char short. Fix it as follows:

```
size = snprintf(command, 0, "/sbin/ifdown %s", INTERFACE);
command = malloc(size+1);
snprintf(command, size+1, "/sbin/ifdown %s", INTERFACE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats the thing that i was missing.